# How should I prune my butterfly pea?

Tags: pruning, vines, overwintering

I have a butterfly pea *[Clitoria ternatea](https://www.rareseeds.com/blog/post/how-to-grow-butterfly-pea)*.  How should I prune it?

I am growing it in zone 8a, so it may not survive it's first winter.  It is currently dormant.  How much can I cut it back in the winter?

The growth habit is mostly a low bush with some vine-like shape.

Comment: Please post a picture, it will someone give you thh answer you are looking for.